# Does django mess up with python's datetime?

Tags: python, django, python-3.3

I have a file that I check it's creation time using ctime. Here is the snippet of code (not complete, just the important part):

```
import time
import pytz
import os
from datetime import datetime

myfile = SOMEWHERE

myfile_ctime = os.path.getctime(myfile)
d = datetime.strptime(time.ctime(myfile_ctime), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
# d here is Tue Mar 25 00:33:40 2014 for example
ny = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
d_ny = ny.localize(d)
mytz = pytz.timezone(MY_TZ_WHATEVER)
myd = d_ny.astimezone(mytz)
final_date = myd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(final_date + "some string") 
# is now 2014-03-25 01:33:40some string, correctly with the timezone.
```

When this is run as a simple python script, everything is ok. But when I run the **same** code inside a function in a `templatetags/myfile.py` that renders to a template in a Django App, when trying to get the date from `time.ctime(myfile_ctime)`, then I get **Tue Mar 25 04:33:40** instead of **Tue Mar 25 00:33:40** from the snippet above (the code is **the same** in the standalone script and in Django - and I concatenate the date with another string).

My question is: I'm using just Python standard libraries, same snippet of code in both places, reading the same file in the same environment. Why the difference? Do settings in settings.py *mangles up* something in the standard libraries? Just being in a Django environment it changes how standard libraries should work? Why when calling standalone everything works as it should?

(I'm behind apache, don't know if this is relevant)

Comment: So it's just the return value of `ctime` that changed, right?

Comment: Django by default uses `America/Chicago` as time zone in settings if you have not defined any. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#time-zone

Comment: @satoru yep, it started with ctime. Since ctime itself is wrong, all other dates have the same problem. I tried `datetime.utcfromtimestamp` instead of `time.ctime` as well but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `./django/conf/__init__.py:126:`, `TZ` environment variable is set based on `settings.py`.

```
os.environ['TZ'] = self.TIME_ZONE
```

My TIME_ZONE is UTC.

That's why a standalone script result is different from a snippet inside Django: when running standalone, this environment variable `TZ`isn't set.

Now, when creating a datetime object from a myfile_ctime, I just need to add tzinfo from my server (`/etc/sysconfig/clock`). My code now looks like this:

```
import time
import pytz
import os
from datetime import datetime

myfile = SOMEWHERE

myfile_ctime = os.path.getctime(myfile)

ny = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
d = datetime.fromtimestamp(myfile_ctime, tz=ny)
mytz = pytz.timezone(MY_TZ_WHATEVER)
myd = d.astimezone(mytz)
final_date = myd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I hope this is useful to someone. As always, read the source. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of the Time Zone settings in settings.py, for more info about Django Time Zone Settings, check this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#time-zone